# How can I hide an active terminal from Ubuntu dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, autostart

I have terminal launch on start up that runs a tty-clock.  Is there a way to hide the icon from the dock?

Here is the /autostart/ entry

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=xfce4-terminal --command /home/noah/bin/clock --geometry=37x7 --hide-borders --hide- scrollbar --hide-toolbar --hide-menubar
Hidden=false 
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_NG]=Terminal
Name=Terminal
Comment[en_NG]=Start Terminal On Startup
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want that? I suspect you would find drop-down terminals like Guake useful.

Comment: I use the tty clock in a terminal instead of the clock on my top bar, it looks nice and is bigger.  I don't need the icon for the terminal on the dock, it just gets in my way.